# how to set environmental variable to Oracle home location?

Tags: linux, oracle

I have installed Oracle RAC 11gr2 on Oracle Linux version 5. During installation I have installed my grid software in location /u01/grid_home. Now my binaries were in /u01/grid_home/bin directory. Now when I need to run any cluster related command I always need to go /u01/grid_home/bin location and run it. Now I want to set that location to my oracle user home location which is /home/oracle so that I can run those cluster command here. Can someone please tell me how can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set ORACLE_HOME path like this

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/grid_home/bin
```

If you need to add to the path, I suppose you could do this

```
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME:/u01/grid_home/bin
```

My Linux box is offline, otherwise I'd test this out... let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it. it didnt work. I have given above commands from /home/oracle and ran some cluster commands and got error saying -bash: crsctl: command not found